# Azure B2C: Error on sign up page when accessed from separated sign in step

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been trying to create a slightly different UI flow from the B2C sign in/sign up sample, but it's causing an error on the sign up page. Here's what's working so far: I've been using the example provided here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml with a few modifications made (such as using Azure AD for social sign in, rather than Facebook). I am using the following technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

and these are the first two orchestration steps:

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Multi-TenantAAD" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

When I run the policy the following screen appears: [Email sign in or sign up plus social sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nTNe.png)

When I click on the sign up button this screen appears: [Email sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1WPX.png)

That's all well and good and working correctly. However, I want to change it so that the initial screen is simply one button for the Microsoft sign in and one button for email sign in. Then once clicking on the email sign in it takes you to the sign in/sign up page. Therefore I have made the following modifications:

I have changed the content definition reference in the technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Sign In With Email</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signuporsignin</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

and I have changed the orchestration steps:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Multi-TenantAAD" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

The 1st step is now just a ClaimsProviderSelection with the target in the 2nd step.

What happens now is that when you run the policy you see this: [Social or Email selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQIFe.png)

And after clicking on the email sign in you see this: [Email sign in or sign up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkBPb.png)

Which is exactly what I wanted, and both sign in methods work correctly. However, the problem now is that if you click on the sign up button, instead of going to the sign up page, you instead see this page: [Sorry we're having trouble signing you in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMgx3.png)

Do you have any idea what could be causing it and how to fix it? I've been playing around with a number of different settings or ways to configure the orchestration steps, but none of them seem to help at all. I'm sure it's an issue with how the local account sign in technical profile connects back to the email sign up claims exchange, but I don't know how to hook them up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, rather than try launch it like the starter pack, instead lets call a technical profile to flag which direction we want to go, either to the federated IdP, or via the normal combined sign in and sign up steps.

To make the Sign In page talk to the Sign Up page, they have to be arranged just like the starter pack, using `Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin"`.

```xml
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="Exchange">
        <DisplayName>Exchange</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText />
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>SetExchangeValues</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Set-ContosoExchange">
          <DisplayName>Microsoft account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Exchange" DefaultValue="Contoso" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Set-LocalExchange">
          <DisplayName>Sign in with email</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Exchange" DefaultValue="LocalSUSI" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="idptest">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ContosoExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ContosoExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Set-ContosoExchange" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Set-LocalExchange" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>Exchange</Value>
              <Value>LocalSUSI</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange-TP" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange-TP" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>Exchange</Value>
              <Value>LocalSUSI</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>Exchange</Value>
              <Value>Contoso</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Multi-TenantAAD" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
```

Comment: Actaully, maybe I spoke too soon. I'm now trying to add in the self service password reset functionality following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy, however the flow produces another error when getting to the sign up page. Do you know how I can work around this?